# Capturing the o/p of "execute immediate" to a variable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the need to capture the o/p of "execute immediate" statement and use that o/p variable in incremental steps execution of the proc.

Like the code is :

```
  var_01 := 'SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM ALL_RESOURCE_MONITOR_MASTER WHERE' || ' ' 
              || 'account_name = ' ||''''|| lv_acct_name_new ||''''|| ' ' || 'AND' || ' '
              || 'rm_type= ' ||''''|| type || ''''||' ' || 'AND' || ' '
              || 'env= ' ||''''|| env || ''''||' ';
  cnt := (execute immediate :var_01);
```

Now post I get the cnt as populated, then I need to run the below if~else statement:

```
if (cnt > 0) then
        return 'execute the statement';
    else
        return 'Resource monitor already present hence insert skipped';
    end if;
```

But the problem is when I try to execute this block I am always getting an error like :

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid expression value (?SqlExecuteImmediateDynamic?) for assignment.
```

Please do provide your inputs on resolving this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi - you can't just assign the output of a sql statement to a variable like that. You need to use a cursor or resultset to process the result of the SQL statement. This is covered in the SQL Scripting documentation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no syntax like `EXECTUE <sql> INTO <output_variable_list> USING <input_variable_list>` known from different dialects.

[EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html):

> Executes a string that contains a SQL statement or a Snowflake Scripting statement.
>
> ```
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<string_literal>'
>  [ USING (bind_variable_1 [, bind_variable_2 ...] ) ] ;
> ```

---

In this scenario there is no need to use dynamic SQL for checking in metadata table as it could be rewritten to use parametrized if-statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ALL_RESOURCE_MONITOR_MASTER
AS
SELECT 'acc1' AS account_name, 'TEST' AS env, 'WAREHOUSE' AS rm_type;
```

Code:

```
DECLARE 
   lv_acct_name_new TEXT := 'acc1';
   type             TEXT := 'WAREHOUSE';
   env              TEXT := 'TEST';
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM ALL_RESOURCE_MONITOR_MASTER
              WHERE account_name = :lv_acct_name_new
                AND rm_type = :type
                AND env = :env
              )) THEN
      RETURN 'Executing some code';
  ELSE
      RETURN 'Resource monitor already present hence insert skipped';       
  END IF;
END;
```